# Want a more efficient method to replace string values

Tags: php, arrays, string, str-replace

I feel like there must be a more efficient way to get the same results.
I am fetching data from an SQL query. Several of those values return either a "Y" or "N" which I replace to display as "Yes" or "No".  So I targeted each field as follows;

```
$pool= $row['POOL'];
$pool= str_replace("Y","Yes",$pool);
$pool= str_replace("N","No",$pool);
echo $pool

$wf= $row['WATERFRONT'];
$wf= str_replace("Y","Yes",$wf);
$wf= str_replace("N","No",$wf);
echo $wf
```

And so on...  is there a more efficient method of grouping all the "Y/N" Fields (POOL, WATERFRONT) together, perhaps with an Array, which then can replace the values? And how would I echo each field?

Answer (score 6):

```
foreach(array('POOL', 'WATERFRONT') as $field) {
    echo str_replace(array('Yes', 'No'), array('Y', 'N'), $row[$field]);
}
```

This just puts the array keys of each Y/N field into an array and then loops through it. Inside the loop it uses `str_replace()` but takes advantage of its [capability to pass arrays for both the values to swap and their replacements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

> If search and replace are arrays, then str_replace() takes a value from each array and uses them to search and replace on subject. If replace has fewer values than search, then an empty string is used for the rest of replacement values. If search is an array and replace is a string, then this replacement string is used for every value of search.

Comment: You took the words (aka: typing) right out of my mouth/fingers. Good answer! Up-voted...

Comment: I second what @Philly2NYC just said

Comment: 100,091 - Now it's (passed) official ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I barely made it today. Just wasn't a whole lot out there to answer. I think summer is in full swing.

Comment: Oh Happy Day! Oh, and on "our" day too (Canada Day) ;-) Plus, I came out of "retirement" this past week or so; just a few where I thought needed an extra hand. A couple of special cases they were.

Comment: Please excuse me, but I'm a real rookie to php. Do I use a loop even if I'm just querying a single row? I've been playing with this, but I don't understand or see how the echo here identifies which field to display. If I pass the values as such: $row = array("POOL" => "Y", "WTRFR" => "N");  then I would: echo $row['POOL'] or echo $row['WATERFRONT']. So I'm not seeing how to isolate the field, which would be displayed in various areas of my page (not just within any loop section). Boy, I really hope that made sense!

Comment: If it's just one row you can skip the loop entirely and use the one line side of it. For example: `echo str_replace(array('Yes', 'No'), array('Y', 'N'), $row['POOL']);`

Comment: I see. But here I'm still writing that entire line for each place I'm displaying the value. Which seems redundant.  I was thinking the Y/N replacement can be consolidated to one area, then it would just recognize to replace the string for X,Y,Z fields.

Comment: My code shows how to do that. I'm not sure what your issue currently is.

Comment: I was trying to avoid having this part of the code for each displaying field "str_replace(array('Yes', 'No'), array('Y', 'N'), ".  I thought I would be able to (1) group all Y/N field, then (2) establish the replacements for Y/N.  That way I can just echo $row['POOL'] or $row['WTRFR'] - (without having to indicate the same str_replace code for each instance.  Perhaps this is accomplished with an IF function?   "If these fields ('POOL','WTRFR') are set with Y/N values, then display "Yes", "No"  ?

Answer (score 0):

str_replace seems excessive for a binary calculation.

You can still use the loop in John Conde's answer, but inside of it I would use a terniary statement since you are expecting Y or N.

```
<?php echo $row[$field] == 'Y' ? 'Yes' : 'No'; ?>
```